# Can't setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to setState in flutter (to change questions) on my test QUIZ app (im learning now). But when i click a button next, question on display is not change. But if i set var value manually, for ex 4, it displays on screen. I use _questionIndex var and add increment when user click next button, can anybody helps me please?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:quiz/widgets/answer.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final QuestionData data = QuestionData();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _countResult = 0;
    int _questionIndex = 2;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('QUIZ')),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff2a375a),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(data.questions[_questionIndex].title,
                  style: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .caption),
            ),
            ...data.questions[_questionIndex].answers
                .map((value) =>
                Answer(
                  title: value['answer'],
                ),)
                .toList(),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  setState(() {
                    _questionIndex = _questionIndex += 1;
                  }),
              child: Text('Next ' '$_questionIndex'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Upon rebuilding a widget, the `build` method is called and in that method you set `_questionIndex` to 2. So it can never reflect a change in UI. Try moving those variables to a higher scope, like `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is not changing dynamically Because you place **_countResult and _questionIndex** inside of widget Method.Try to place these variables outside of widget method.
When every time setState() is called it rerun build method.

Answer (score 3):

1. The problem is you declaration of the `_questionIndex`. You are
   declaring it as a local variable in the `build` function. This is
   why it is declared freshly every time you call `setState()`, since
   `setState()` calls again the `build` function.

   But what you want to do is saving the `_questionIndex` as well as
   `_countResult` as a member variable of your `State`. So it is
   declared independently of your `build()` function.
2. The second thing:

```
_questionIndex += 1;
```

is equal to

```
_questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
```

So this is one statement too much:

```
_questionIndex = questionIndex += 1;
```

My code suggestion would look like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:quiz/widgets/answer.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final QuestionData data = QuestionData();
  int _countResult = 0;
  int _questionIndex = 2;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('QUIZ')),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff2a375a),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(data.questions[_questionIndex].title,
                  style: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .caption),
            ),
            ...data.questions[_questionIndex].answers
                .map((value) =>
                Answer(
                  title: value['answer'],
                ),)
                .toList(),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  setState(() {
                    _questionIndex += 1;
                  }),
              child: Text('Next ' '$_questionIndex'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),);
  }
}
```